# Object reference not set error if linq query doesn't find a matching record?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have this code

```
public object GetMaxReportNo(string OfficeStationCombination = "")
        {
            try
            {
                InspectionReport InspectionReport = new InspectionReport();
                string VelosiReportNo = "";

                var query = uow.InspectionReportRepository.GetQueryable().AsQueryable();

                if (query.Any())
                {
                    VelosiReportNo = query.Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination)).OrderByDescending(x => x.InspectionReportID).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault().VelosiReportNo;
                }

                return VelosiReportNo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This line:

```
VelosiReportNo = query.Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination)).OrderByDescending(x => x.InspectionReportID).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault().VelosiReportNo;
```

throws error:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

When I pass a parameter for which a record doesn't yet exist in database. But, I can't figure out that what it's returning? How do I control it?

I have handled `null` but that doesn't work. How do I handle in case of not fidning the record so I can take decision on the basis of that?

Comment: check whether object is not null then use its property.

Comment: You're trying to do too much in a single line of code. Break up the pieces and check for null along the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
query.Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination)).Any()
```

did the trick.

Full code;

```
                if (query.Any())
                {
                    if (query.Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination)).Any())
                    {
                        VelosiReportNo = query.Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination)).OrderByDescending(x => x.InspectionReportID).FirstOrDefault().VelosiReportNo;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        VelosiReportNo = null;
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Posting Questions ,

To resolve your problem you need to check your result if is not null before trying to retrieve properties value from it .

**You can check the code below nothing magic:**

1. I supressed Try/Catch because there is no interest to catch and rethrow it .
2. I supress DefaultIfEmpty beacause default value of string is null .
3. I add a cheking for querying result  if is null or not .

   ```
   public object GetMaxReportNo(string OfficeStationCombination = "")
   {
           InspectionReport InspectionReport = new InspectionReport();
           string VelosiReportNo = "";

           var query = uow.InspectionReportRepository.GetQueryable().AsQueryable();

           if (query.Any())
           {
               var queryResult = query.Where(x => x.VelosiReportNo.Contains(OfficeStationCombination))
                                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.InspectionReportID)
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
               if (queryResult != null)
                   VelosiReportNo = queryResult.VelosiReportNo;
           }

           return VelosiReportNo;
   }
   ```

Comment: that does't work actually. I have tried it. thanks anyway

Comment: @PostingQuestions what is the error ?